# How can I create a custom colored icon font?

Tags: font, emoji

How can I create custom colored icon font as Apple did for emoticons?

I'd also need a font making tool that imports .svg images.

Answer (score 3):

For font making the common OS X tools are FontLab, FontForge, and Glyphs.

I understand the Color Emoji font uses png color bitmaps in two sizes in a proprietary “sbix” table, but have not yet seen info on how to make that table.

Answer (score 0):

This link explains how to make a custom color font.

http://www.pixelambacht.nl/2014/compyx-a-multicolor-8bit-font/

hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.